# Why is my jda discord bot not sending messages

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I dont think ive done anything wrong but clearly i have, ill type >test and nothing will happen.
Ive been following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGrD8AZfTig&t=0s) and changing things when necceserry as it was uploaded in 2018

Main.java:

```
package diaduck.Playground;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.OnlineStatus;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity;

public class Main {
    public static JDA jda;
    public static String prefix = ">";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        
        String token = "ODU4NzA1MTA0NTY4MTg4OTQ4.YNiBcg.0000000000000000000"
        
        JDABuilder jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(token);
        jda.setStatus(OnlineStatus.DO_NOT_DISTURB);
        jda.setActivity(Activity.listening("the kids scream"));
        
        jda.addEventListeners(new Commands());
        
        jda.build();
    }
}
```

Commands.java

```
package diaduck.Playground;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class Commands extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onGuildMessageRecived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");
        
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "test")) {
            event.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Ok").queue();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try chaning the prefix String to "!"

Answer (score 0):

do you use the latest build of JDA? If not, then I recommend you to, since the videos you're following/watching (2018) are super old and really bad for learning. Use the [JDA documents](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/index.html)

**To quote the [JDA Wiki](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19%29-Troubleshooting#my-event-listener-code-is-not-executed):**

[image: TroubleShooting]